# Add ProgressBar while loading UI content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have used Google Place Picker API in my app
So Place Picker takes time to load, so I want to use ProgressBar for a certain time till the api is completely loaded
and is there any way to work with complex UI
for eg my main page contains lots of data and it takes around 5-6sec to completely load it,so is there a way to add progressbar over there also?
please Help i am new to android

Comment: Check the example in [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your progress dialog:

```
ProgressDialog progress;
```

When you're ready to start the progress dialog:

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
    "dialog message", true);
```

and to make it go away when you're done:

```
if (progress != null) {
   progress.dismiss();
}
```